# How to inject JOOQ's DSLcontext in Kotlin class

Tags: spring, kotlin, jooq

I am using JOOQ with Kotlin, Spring and PostgreSQL. I'm able to run JOOQ generator and query data. The problem is that I am not able to inject DSLcontext in repository class constructor.

It throws following exception:

Field `dslContext` in someRepository required a bean of type `org.jooq.DSLContext` that could not be found.

Injection looks like this:

```
@Repository
class SomeRepositoryImpl(private val dslContext: DSLContext): SomeRepository
{

}
```

Cheers,
Ondrej

Comment: I suspect this question will need a bit more context. What's your complete configuration? Where is your injectable `DSLContext` configured?

Comment: I've followed the jooq kotlin example and jooq spring boot example. I'll create small sample project to demonstrate my problem.

Answer (score 2):

I had a wrong configuratuion as Lukas Eder pointed out. It starts to work after I've added following dependency to pom.xml file:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jooq</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Thanks for your help,
Ondrej